# Stretch div all the way to the bottom without overflowing

Tags: css

Can anyone please help me to fill the width of parent container and stretch it all the way to bottom without overflowing. Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vn50gka2/1/#&togetherjs=p1VVmrhCtA

```
.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.layout {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 60px auto
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Container is the div I'm trying to fix. The toolbar and layout can not be changed. And also just because I want to reuse the container I really wish to not use any calculation or any hardcoded height numbers.. I don't know if this is possible

Comment: How about using CSS calc for `.container`'s width & height? Below values are based on the fiddle:
`.container { height:calc(100% - 60px); width:calc(100% - 16px); position:absolute; left:auto; top:auto; }`

You might need need to re-adjust these values based on your real css styles: `60px` is the `.layout`'s top margin and `16px` is for the `body`'s horizontal margin.

Comment: @oq Thanks for the comment. Yes that's the way I'm trying to avoid because I'm trying to reuse the "container" div in other screens( with added menu bar at the top, modal without a toolbar etc.). If there isn't any other no calc solution then I will have to go with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var toolbarheight = $(".toolbar").height();
var windowheight  = $(this).height();
var divheight =  windowheight - toolbarheight -10;
console.log(divheight)

$(".mydiv").height(divheight);
})
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
paddin:0;}
.toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}


.layout {
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar">
  Toolbar
</div>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container mydiv">
    <div>
      stretch to bottom without overflow
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

well this full height for ur  div using jquery!
added -10 is difference between your toolbar height and your layout top margin!